# Matlab: create close packed layer of circles

Tags: matlab, math, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to create a close packed layer by generating my center points like a box and then shear the point in order to create a close packed layer of circles..
[more info can be found here](http://chemistry.osu.edu/~woodward/ch754/str_cp.htm)

but I'm having some difficulties.. My code so far is

```
%% Trying out the shear function
rad=2; n=3;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(0   :   rad*2   :   rad*(n-1)*2    ,   ...
             0   : sqrt(2*(2*rad)^2)/2 : sqrt(2*(2*rad)^2)/2*(n-1));
xyBox = [reshape(X,1,numel(X)) ; reshape(Y,1,numel(Y))];
Sh = @(m) [1 m; 0 1];       % horizontal shear - slope is qual to 1/m
slope = sqrt(3);

shearedCoordinates = Sh(1/slope) * xyBox;
figure; plot(xyBox(1,:),xyBox(2,:),'k.');
for i= 1:(numel(shearedCoordinates)/2)
    hold on;
    circle(shearedCoordinates(1,i),shearedCoordinates(2,i),rad)
    plot(shearedCoordinates(1,i),shearedCoordinates(2,i),'bx')
    hold off;
end
axis equal
```

[image: sorta packed circles]

Don't really understand the math behind the Sh, but can just see that it does a damn good job twisting (shearing) points. I calculated a slope of square root 3 should give the right place, but it looks lige there is something wrong with my y distances...

the circle function is

```
function circle(x,y,r)
    angle=0:0.01:2*pi; 
    xp=r*cos(angle);
    yp=r*sin(angle);
    plot(x+xp,y+yp,'r');
end
```

*** SOLUTION ***

```
%% Trying out the shear function
rad=2; n=3;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(0   :   rad*2   :   rad*(n-1)*2    , ...
    0   : sqrt(3)*rad   : sqrt(3)*rad*(n-1));
xyBox = [reshape(X,1,numel(X)) ; reshape(Y,1,numel(Y))];
Sh = @(m) [1 m; 0 1];       % horizontal shear - slope is qual to 1/m
slope = sqrt(3);

shearedCoordinates = Sh(1/slope) * xyBox;
figure; plot(xyBox(1,:),xyBox(2,:),'k.');
for i= 1:(numel(shearedCoordinates)/2)
    hold on;
    circle(shearedCoordinates(1,i),shearedCoordinates(2,i),rad)
    plot(shearedCoordinates(1,i),shearedCoordinates(2,i),'bx')
    hold off;
end
axis equal
```

(don't forget to vote up if you found it useful)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By my reckoning your mistake (or perhaps just the first one that I can see) is in the y-spacing of the lines of circle centres.  You have the expression

```
0   : sqrt(2*(2*rad)^2)/2 : sqrt(2*(2*rad)^2)/2*(n-1)
```

for laying out the circle centres.  I think that the vertical stride (or step value) should be `rad*sqrt(3)/2` which would give you:

```
0   : rad*sqrt(3)/2 : sqrt(2*(2*rad)^2)/2*(n-1)
```

Unless I've made a mistake (entirely possible) the height of a unit equilateral triangle is `sqrt(3)/2` and that ought to be your y-spacing.

Comment: You are correct that the height is wrong. It should have been sqrt(3)*rad. Been looking at too many numbers yesterday.

Comment: Just added the final solution

Comment: I maintain that the altitude of an equilateral triangle of side `a` is `a*sqrt(3)/2` not, as you have it in your comment, `a*sqrt(3)`.

Comment: Your equation is absolutely correct - as is mine. A equilateral triangle (build by circles) with the side length as "a" would mean that "a=2*rad" - so giving "a*sqrt(3)/2 = (2*rad)*sqrt(3)/2 = rad*sqrt(3)".

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment - it lead me to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have not had a chance to go through the code in Matlab yet but by just looking at the figure you posted I agree that shear is working. However those circles would overlap even if you used the pre-shear centers. Is that what you mean?

Comment: shear is working just fine. When you say pre/shear I assume you mean the black centers. If they are plotted from the black centers, then yes they will overlap.

Comment: Actually, maybe on second look we were wrong about shear. If you look at the first figure in the link you included and try to rotate them back to undo the shear, or unpack them, the distance between centres along the y has to increase. Instead in your figure the centres have just been translated along the x. I think that even if you got the initial distances right and then sheared this way, you would not achieve the packing effect.

Comment: Check the figure with red spheres in the Slip via dislocation motion paragraph here: http://www.doitpoms.ac.uk/tlplib/dislocations/printall.php